# Trigger Only Work Once/Debug

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I created a trigger to, when a record is inserted or updated in a table T1, he mirror this in a table T2 (following some conditions).

In the first statement (insert) in T1, the triggers works well (copy everything in T1 to T2). But after the first, the trigger won't run anymore (using Insert or update clause).

Code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Replicacao]
   ON  [dbo].[ImportacaoXML]
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID, ProgramacaoBarcas.Data 
               FROM ProgramacaoBarcas, inserted 
               WHERE ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = inserted.ViagemID 
                 AND ProgramacaoBarcas.Data = inserted.Data)        
    BEGIN 
      UPDATE ProgramacaoBarcas 
      SET ViagemID = inserted.ViagemID, Data = inserted.Data, 
          Extra = inserted.Extra, Modalidade = inserted.Modalidade,
          FleetID = inserted.FleetID, Partida = inserted.Partida, 
          Chegada = inserted.Chegada, Capacidade = inserted.Capacidade, 
          LocationID = inserted.LocationID, DestinoID = inserted.DestinoID, 
          CodLinha = inserted.CodLinha
      FROM inserted 
      WHERE ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = inserted.ViagemID 
        AND ProgramacaoBarcas.Data = inserted.Data 
        AND ProgramacaoBarcas.Bloqueada = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO ProgramacaoBarcas (ViagemID, Data, Extra, Modalidade, FleetID, Partida, Chegada, Capacidade, LocationID, DestinoID, CodLinha, Bloqueada)
         SELECT 
             ViagemID, Data, Extra, Modalidade, FleetID, Partida, Chegada, 
             Capacidade, LocationID, DestinoID, CodLinha, 0 
         FROM inserted      
    END 
END
```

Anyone have any clue ? I searched to logs, but found nothing. Is there any way to debug a trigger ?

(Newbie here, please be patient)

**Obs:** I found the solution. The code is correct now.

Comment: What happens if delete records in a T1 table?

Comment: Nothing. It's "not important" right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is right in the beginning, when you check for existance of data on the `ProgramacaoBarcas` table. So, you are doing this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID, ProgramacaoBarcas.Data 
           FROM ProgramacaoBarcas 
           WHERE ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = ViagemID 
             AND ProgramacaoBarcas.Data = Data)
```

See the `WHERE` conditions?, you are comparing two columns with themselves: `ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = ViagemID` and `ProgramacaoBarcas.Data = Data`. So basically you are doing a `SELECT` with no `WHERE` (not entirely true since `NULL`s are equal to nothing, but you get the point). So, on your first execution, the table is empty, and go to the `INSERT` part of your trigger, and populate some data. Since now there is data on that table, all other executions of the trigger go the `UPDATE` part of your trigger. So, if the trigger gets called because of you inserted data, that data won't get inserted on the second table, and if new data that isn't on the second table already gets updated, the trigger would seem that it's doing nothing since it can't `UPDATE` data that doesn't exists. Hopefully this clarify things for you.

Comment: I though the _ViagemID_ in this statement, `ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = ViagemID`, for example, would be from table `ImportacaoXML.ViagemID`, not from `ProgramacaoBarcas`. But if i write `ProgramacaoBarcas.Data = ImportacaoXML.Data`, SQL gives me _"The multi-part identifier ImportacaoXML.ViagemID could not be associated"_. How can i acomplish that comparison ? I just need to check, if exist in `ProgramacaoBarcas`, update, if not, insert in `ProgramacaoBarcas`

Comment: @Juliano You aren't using any other table on that statement. See the `FROM ProgramacaoBarcas`, why would the trigger assume that `ViagemID` is supposed to come from the `ImportacaoXML` table?. And, since you aren't using any other table, you can't say `ImportacaoXML.ViagemID`, since it's not defined on your query. You should use a `JOIN` there for that. But really, you should change your logic to account when more than one record gets updated or inserted.

Comment: I got it. In the where statement, i changed the where to compare using the inserted table. So, `ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID = inserted.ViagemID`. Thanks @Lamak.

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize two tables by using [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Replicacao] ON [dbo].[ImportacaoXML]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  MERGE ProgramacaoBarcas AS target
  USING inserted AS source
    ON target.ViagemID = source.ViagemID
      AND target.Data = source.Data      
  WHEN MATCHED AND ProgramacaoBarcas.Bloqueada = 0 THEN 
    UPDATE SET ViagemID = source.ViagemID, Data = source.Data, 
               Extra = source.Extra, Modalidade = source.Modalidade,
               FleetID = source.FleetID, Partida = source.Partida, 
               Chegada = source.Chegada, Capacidade = source.Capacidade, 
               LocationID = source.LocationID, DestinoID = source.DestinoID, 
               CodLinha = source.CodLinha
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ViagemID, Data, Extra, Modalidade, FleetID, Partida, 
            Chegada, Capacidade, LocationID, DestinoID, CodLinha, Bloqueada)
    VALUES (
            ViagemID,Data, Extra, Modalidade, FleetID, Partida,
            Chegada, Capacidade, LocationID, DestinoID, CodLinha, 0);
END
```